# How to get a webhook notification for a paid bill in Xero?

Tags: node.js, xero-api

How can one get a bill paid notification by webhook?
Although webhooks have been configured and work correctly, there seems no resources available to explain how a paid bill can be processed with own third party integration.

Comment: The documentation suggests that the closest you might pick up on is monitoring when an invoice is updated - would that trigger your webhook on a payment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Invoices webhooks will trigger on an update. Payment being added counts as an update.

You would need to add some additional logic as not all updates will be the result of a payment being added. The specifics of this will depend on if the Bill should be fully paid, or if a part-payment is of interest.

The simplified logic would be something like:

1. Receive a webhook for an update on an invoice.
2. Check to see if any payments have been added.